# MS Access - Form tries to create new record on open and record jumps about a continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have two issues with my database, which I think are linked together.

Firstly if `tblDeliveries` is empty and `frmMainView` is opened it comes up with "You must enter a value in the 'tblDeliveries.deliverySlot' field" but the form shouldn't be trying to create a record and I can't see any reason why it would. Opening `frmDailyView` (which is a subform of `frmMainView`) doesn't show this behaviour but it is the one with the continuous form on...

Secondly if `tblDeliveries` has one (or more) rows the first row of the table will jump about... For example in `frmMainView` if the date of the first record is set to 23/01/2015 and you navigate to the 24/01/2015 and click anywhere on the subform and then press F5 to refresh the record will have jumped to that date, the date even changes in `tblDeliveries`.

I have no idea why it's doing it, I even removed all of the VBA code for the form to stop it, but it happens anyway.

If anyone has come across anything like this before, please let me know how you fixed it, or any suggestions would be very welcome. Thanks!

**EDIT: If you download the database, add your computer login name to tblUsers. Also the date is UK formatted, so might need tweaking to work with US dates.**

[The offending database (1.5MB)](https://app.box.com/s/dbkzr7cll9dod9acnhubrjlkcx5a84u2)

Comment: I'm afraid I created it.

Comment: The backup was made when I was tinkering with some controls, it probably also suffered with the problem but I've only recently noticed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue, thanks to some of the comments I realised I could just give the `deliverySlot` field a default value with a number outside of the range it would look for, I set it to 99, but it only looks for 1-20. The date still jumps around but since it's not in the range of the query it's hidden. It's resolved both issues.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your database, several issues are occurring.

You first issue can be resolved by going into the Design View of the table **tblDeliveries**, select the *deliverySlot* field and change Required (in bottom panel) from Yes to No.

Your second issue is multi-faceted with many issues but a critical problem is that the parent-child link field, *deliveryDate*, between the main form and subform is missing in the recordsource of the sub form and the field's table origin is not in the query's join statements. For me, I can't even update anything in subform (all boxes are grayed out).

Essentially, you are trying to normalize Delivery Dates and Delivery Times (one-to-many) but the left join query (**qryDeliveryIncBlanks**) setup is not aligned to this effect. You user login also does not integrate smoothly into frmMainView. My ultimate advice is revamp your database design relational model then use forms as the visual representation of those related tables.

Comment: I did the one-to-many so I could populate the form without having to generate each record for each timeslot. There is double click event on the time 07:00 to generate a new entry which unlocks the greyed out controls. It's still a work in progress as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

I am not re-iterating the points of @Parfait.

Access Forms have a property `DataEntry`. If it is set to `Yes` (or `True` in VBA), then the form will open itself pointing to a new empty data record. Set this property to `No` (`False` in VBA).

If you want to give the user the possibility to manually enter a new record, set the property `AllowAdditions` to `Yes` and to `No` otherwise. `Yes` displays an empty record marked with a star `*` and the end of the data sheet or continuous form.